# Best way to distribute a Java app with resource files (DB connection parameters, images, ...)

Tags: java, jdbc, launch4j

I want to distribute a Java application that connects to an external database using a Java properties file. My issue is that once my project is exported as a Jar file (and then as an EXE using Launch4j) in a different place than my project's root folder, the connection to my database fails and most of my pictures are not loaded.

Regarding just the connection, I have tried several things to read the connection properties written in an external file, which is located in a source folder :

[image: Project structure]

The code :

[image: Code reading the properties file with the connection parameters]

I also tried to let the property file in the root folder of my project: both way work when running the project, but fail when launching the jar or the exe.

First I thought it was just because of the exportation of my project, that maybe failed due to some wrong settings. But I am started to think that I may have a wrong understanding on how to import resources into a Java project, even thought I followed several topics on that subject on Stackoverflow.

So :

- What is the best way to include properties files in a way that makes it possible to export them in a Jar/exe file ?
- Or, should these files be included after generating the Jar, by referencing them when producing the exe ? How would that be ?

As the connection file contains some sensible data (ie. the password to connect to the database), I hoped there was an official way to keep that file protected from unwanted access after exporting the Jar/exe file.

Thank you a lot for helping.
I can provide more code and pictures if needed.

Comment: add a resources folder to your project path. When you build, the resources folder should be included in the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources (as in a jar) are not File (on the file system). Use

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/conf/connexxion.properties");`
```

For that place the `conf` under `/resources`.

Comment: Do you mean `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` ? If so, it works ! So does that mean that I need to do that for my pictures as well ? Thank you

Comment: Yes; corrected. kavita's getClassLoader variant works too, there the path is absolute, and should not start with a `/`. An URL of getResource might sometimes be more appropriate - for the images. BTW resource paths are case sensitive - as opposed to file paths under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
String configFile = "conf/connexion.properties";
InputStream inputStream = this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFile);
Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
if (inputStream  != null) {
    props.load(in);
}else{
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

(or)

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/conf/connexion.properties");
if (url != null)
     prop.load(url.openStream());
}
```